# Too Much memory usage for application pool in Odata Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a web api(2) for odata. i'm running an simple query with 100 rows result. but application pool is growing too much.

WebApiConfig:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Transaction>("Transaction");
builder.EntitySet<Resource>("Resource");
              ......
              ......
         Some other EntitySet
              ......
              ......
builder.EntitySet<User>("User");
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

What's Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. I didn't install .net framework 4.5.
Installed version was .net framework 4